# pycryptodome module cannot be imported as wheel

Tags: python

I have downloaded the **pycryptodome** python module wheel format file (*pycryptodome.whl*) from [this link](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/#files).

Now when I try to **import** and use it as follows

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
```

I get

```
ImportError: No module named Crypto.PublicKey
```

I have another module called **PyVMOMI** (*pyvmomi.whl*) where I do not see this problem. I can very well import any of its module files without any error.

Note: the directory where the ***.whl** file is located is set in the **PYTHONPATH** variable already.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wheels are not meant to be directly importable. While this *may* work with simple packages, it is not guaranteed to work for all wheels so I wouldn't rely on it. See [PEP 491](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0491/), section [Is it possible to import Python code directly from a wheel file?](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0491/#is-it-possible-to-import-python-code-directly-from-a-wheel-file)
2. Even with ordinary zipfiles in `sys.path`, no dynamic libs will be imported from zipfiles. Quoting [PEP 273](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0273/), section [Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0273/#specification):

> Any files may be present in the zip archive, but only files `*.py` and `*.py[co]` are available for import. Zip import of dynamic modules (`*.pyd`, `*.so`) is disallowed.

This is what happens with `pycryptodome`: it ships C extension modules, precompiled into dynamic libs, which are not imported from wheel. You will need to install the wheel to be able to use the code from extensions:

```
$ pip install pycryptodome
```